# Rotating images + content - jQuery or MooTools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, cycle, image-rotation

I've found a feature on two different websites that I'd like to include on one of my web projects, but I can't figure out how they're doing it. I think they're using either jQuery or mootools, but I'm not sure.

- http://www.x-plane.com/index_desktop.html

I'm new here so I don't have the reputation to post the other link, but if you do a Google search for "Andrews Institute of Orthopaedics" its the top result. I'll see if I can answer a few questions to earn my keep.

The thing that I like about these is that the images and text (including links) are all rotated together. I've done a few web searches related to cycle, rotate and slide but it's not coming together for me. Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you linked is using [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) for this (usually because that's what the author knew, as with most libraries), and it is custom script they've written.  However, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) has a lot of plugins with various styles, just see what one fits your taste best.  I'd suggest taking a [look here](http://www.queness.com/post/222/10-jquery-photo-gallery-and-slider-plugins) and a [look here](http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/).

Anything you find can be automated on a timer like the site you linked, or use buttons, or both.  These are all pretty flexible, I'd start by finding the plugin you want, try and get it going, then asking a question here if you have problems getting it to behave exactly how you want.

Comment: These are exactly what I was looking for, thanks Nick. I may have questions as I go, but this will get me a long way toward my goal.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: @Lenwood - Glad to help!  If this answers your question, please click the check-mark beside to accept it as the answer...this helps future users who google and find your question quickly get help.  Of course, the same holds true for any future questions you ask as well, thanks :)